# HTML element aside from headers <h1><h2>, ect

Tags: html, css, tags, styling

I was browsing related issues for my question but I can't seem to find the answer for it. Anyways, I want to know if I can still use the p or div tags instead of header tags when I have already used both (p and div tags) as plain text on my site. The reason is that I only want to have one header tag h1 present in my site. I tried to tweak some parts and got lost along the way. Sadly, after a couple of testing, it did not work... I was wondering if it's possible or if there's any other HTML tag that I can use other than header tag. Any response from you guys will be very much appreciated. =)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, liza28!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Why can't you use header tags for your headers? Can you maybe post a snippet of code demonstrating the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome but I can't post here the code since I'm still working on it. =)

Anyways, it's a client site and they wanted to still use the sifr but without the other header tags. We currently have h1 and h2 which is used in the Drupal blocks formatting. Thus, they wanted it the css to be in a div or p so we can eliminate the h2. Sorry for the confusion.

Again, the idea is to replace the h2 with a div or p or other html tags with the attributes of h2 and still use the sifr. Thanks again for all your replies. I truly appreciated it. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a `<p>` look however you like, for example:

```
<p class="header">This is a header</p>
```

with

```
p.header { font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold; }
```

but I would recommend *against* it. The reason is that HTML is (ostensibly) semantic so if you declare:

```
<h3>This is a header</h3>
```

you're actually saying (semantically) that the given text *is* a heading of some sort. Remember you have `<h1>` through `<h6>` and you can pick and choose which of them you use. There is no need to use `<h1>` to use `<h2>` and so on.

This is also useful for those visually impaired as something styled as a heading won't be indicated as such to those using screen readers but a heading will be. You should cater for accessibility issues where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* style a div, span, or p to look like a heading and then use it in place off an h1-h6.  That is exactly contrary to the spirit behind the rule of thumb that you shouldn't have more than one h1 on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `P` and `DIV` tags over and over. If you need to, style them to look like `H1`'s.

```
p.title {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
p.header2 {
  background: url("bg.jpg");
}
```

--

```
<p class="title">My Title</p>
<p>And this paragraph will simply be regular text.</p>

<p class="title header2">My Other Title, with a Background Image</p>
<p>And this paragraph will also be regular text.</p>
```

Comment: wow thanks Jonathan for your prompt response. I might have missed declaring the class in the css that's why it did not work. Anyways, the current h2 that I have has an image background in display. Maybe I need time to learn more the structure of the site. I'm tweaking a drupal site. Any other tips from you will be very much helpful so please keep them coming. I'll let you know if it's successful/

Comment: by the way, I forgot to indicate that this issue is related to using sifr. Thanks!

Comment: liza28, I've updated my example to demonstrate how you can give some paragraphs background images.

Comment: Why would you want to style paragraphs to look like headings, instead of just using headings directly? This is a bad idea in general; tools which extract the outline of your site (like the Google bot, or screen readers) won't see these paragraphs as headings.

Comment: Brian, because the OP already used their H1 tags, and you aren't suppose to use more than one instance of each Header tag per page. I answered the question, I didn't push my personal perspective.

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` is a useful addition, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to remember SEO on your site.  Presumably this is why you only want one H1 tag?

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` `<strong>` and `<em>` are others you can use inside your `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

i would use `<div>` or `<span>` tags and use ids or classes to control the style. use ids if there is only once instance or classes if you want to repeat this style. you can also use multiple classes on one element

for example

```
<div id="text">Text Here</div>

<span class="red">This would be red</span>

<div class="red big">This would be big and red</div>
```

with css

```
#text{ font-size: 20px; }
.red{ color: red; }
.big{ font-size: 40px; }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple h1's or h2's and just target them like this:

```
<div id="header"><h1>Title of page/h1></div>
<div id="main"><h1>Title of article</h1></div>

#header h1{ color:red;}
#main h1{ color:blue;}
```

It's not quite what you're asking. I suspect Google is a bit smarter than single H1 approaches.